# Self hosted net.tcp wcf in a Kubernetes container access via Loadbalance IP of kuberenetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I have self hosted a .NET framework 4.x version of WCF with net.tcp binding console app, which is running in Azure k8s contianer, as a selfhosted wcf service

exposed as [net.tcp://CONTAINERIP:5000/WCFServiceName](http://net.tcp://CONTAINERIP:5000/WCFServiceName)

and the port 5000 is exposed via Loadbalancer type ingress service

so the client will be accessing this service like below

[net.tcp://LoadBalancerIP:5000/containerAppName/WCFServiceName](http://net.tcp://LoadBalancerIP:5000/containerAppName/WCFServiceName)

But using the loadbalancer ip is not forwarding the request to container - getting the error.

'There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://LoadBalancerIp:5000/ContainerAppName/WCFServiceName that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.'

LB Yaml

```
spec:
  clusterIP: IP.ADDRESS.OF.CLUSTER
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: nettcp
    nodePort: 30412
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: CONTAINERAPPNAME
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: LB.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS
```

Any idea or suggesions ??

Comment: I'd suggest posting the loadbalancer yaml.

Comment: @mmking added the lb yaml

Comment: Can this WCF service be accessed normally? I mean whether WCF can run normally.

Comment: yes, i did try to call the container IP host URL within container - i can create proxy channel to consume it within container. But when try to create proxy with load balancer IP its not able to get soap actions

Comment: Then this should be a Kuberenetes problem.

Comment: How do you define the ingress for the WCF? How do you deploy the WCF and the service for it?

Answer (score 2):

Guys thanks for the inputs,

Found the reason for the issue, since the app is deployed using the LoadBalancer type service, its not required to provide APP Name in the URL.

when the outside world access the service :

[net.tcp://LoadBalancerIP:5000/containerAppName/WCFServiceName](http://net.tcp://LoadBalancerIP:5000/containerAppName/WCFServiceName) - WONT WORK

[net.tcp://LoadBalancerIP:5000/WCFServiceName](http://net.tcp://LoadBalancerIP:5000/WCFServiceName) - THIS WORKS !!! (Solution)

or

when we do the self hosting we need to include the app name in the URI framing to host the WCF TCP Service.